# Annoying/Pushy Co-worker making remarks on my productivity

Tags: colleagues

I have this overachieving coworker and we have the same job functions. My production rate is good, always meet deadlines/goals, and my reviews are always excellent.

This person constantly messages me asking what I am doing at different times of the day or complaining that my rates are slow or my work not as good as theirs.

I have brought it up to another person at work to have another point of view who suggested it was inappropriate to be on my back all the time, criticizing or being pushy about my work. Would appreciate any suggestions as what to with my situation.

Comment: Why don't you try ignoring it. The only person who's assessment you should care about is your boss/manager.

Comment: Keep a copy of the messages and go to your boss and tell them you are being slowed down by your colleague's continual interruptions.

Comment: Hello all, Will try blocking the person at first but will escalate if this continues in some other way. He/she can always talk to me or email me if something work related does come up. Thank you all for the quick answers and feedback!!

Comment: Does this person message you to your personal phone or IM? Or is it to your company phone/IM?

Comment: It is only through company IM.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate here, this guy could be acting on info/gossip from your manager. If he's the golden boy of the office, then perhaps your manager has discussed your performance with him and that's why he's so confident to IM you over the company's IM service. Better have a discussion with your manager IMO.

Answer (score 14):

> Would appreciate any suggestions as what to with my situation.

Given that this person is not your boss, and that your reviews are already excellent and satisfactory, I say that **you can safely ignore the provocations and pushy remarks from this coworker.**

Keep on with your good work and meeting your deadlines and you will be fine.

Joe suggested in comments that you could block this person if the remarks and messages are too insistent. This could help stop the messages, but one downside is that this person will not be able to reach out to you the moment they actually have a work-related topic to discuss.

**If these remarks and messages ever start to affect your productivity, consider documenting them and bringing this up to your boss** and telling them that it is harming your productivity.

Comment: "this person will not be able to reach out to you the moment they actually have a work-related topic to discuss." - They could walk over to the person, or in the case of remote work, send an email.  Blocking them on an IM based application seems appropriate due to their behavior (or simply ignoring those inappropriate messages).

Comment: @Ramhound good point, if this is a personal IM then blocking will not have drawbacks... if it is a business IM blocking may have such drawback... asked OP for clarification if this is personal IM or company's to then adapt my answer. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Ramhound it seems that this is through company's IM, so blocking this person could indeed have drawbacks

Comment: I would recommend OP to bring up this behavior to their manager. The coworker is wasting everyone's time "checking" up on OP. I don't think blocking is truly an option with work IM especially since this person is a coworker.

Comment: As an intermediate step, OP can ignore/block them and once a day skim over the messages and check if anything substantial is in there. If he complains about slow answer rates, OP can just state that he has to focus on his work and therefore cuts out potential distractions for most of the day.

Answer (score 1):

Though it sounds as though you are confident you are in good standing, check in with your manager if you have any doubt.  Upon further prodding from your coworker, invite them to take up your perceived slipshod work with your manager.

"I'm sorry you feel that way.  It is within your rights to address this with [manager name].  Good day."

Comment: This could actually backfire.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't ignore them. You have to work with this person, you need to resolve this issue.

First off, it does pay to be super-sure this person was not asked to supervise you in some way. Maybe you are already sure? All good. If not, just have a quiet word with you manager, and seek clarification.

Ensure that you keep any task tracking software up to date if it exists, and calmly direct them to that if they want to know what's going on. If you don't have task tracking software, consider speaking to your manager to organise a daily or weekly standup, so the whole team is aware of what everyone is working on.

If they offer unsolicited advise about how to proceed with a task, you can simply thank them, but say that you are not interested in advise at this stage. Or you can listen to them. It's really up to you, but through your communications, make it clear that you will consider what they are saying, and you are not following orders (though I would not use that language).

If they ever question your competency or performance you must shut it down. It is a form of bullying and harassment trying to belittle someone. Let them know that it is inappropriate, and invite them to take it up with your manager if they have legitimate concerns. Do not JADE (Justify, Argue, Defend, or Explain) yourself or your performance.

If it continues, you should raise this issue with you manager. It is perfectly acceptable for your manager to raise issues with your competency or performance, as they are able to offer solutions and put in place procedures to help you. But it is absolutely pointless coming from a peer if it's unsolicited and unwanted.

My last point is that you shouldn't view this person as an overachiever. They are a coworker, and there is more to achieving than meeting deadlines. It also includes being able to work with others, and being sensitive and supportive to the needs of those around you.